# Issue with Batch file input for "War Games" game

Tags: batch-file, cmd

If you are familiar with the 1983 movie "War Games" you should remember the part where the computer ask him "Shall We Play a Game". I have been trying to recreate that and this is what I have so far. The issue is after I enter the password the Command Prompt window closes out. Can someone help me find my mistake?

```
@echo off
title Shall We Play a Game?
color 0b

set /a tries=3
set password=Joshua
:top
echo  %tries% Tries Remaining
set /p pass=Password:
if %pass%==%password% (
goto correct
)
set /a tries=%tries -1
if %tries%==0 (
goto penalty
)
cls
goto top
:penalty
echo CONNECTION TERMINATED
pause
exit
:correct
goto greeting

:greeting
echo Shall we play a game?
echo y/n
set input=
if %input%=y goto y
if %input%=n goto n

:y
echo How about
echo Chess
echo Tic-Tac-Toe
echo Snake
echo Global Thermonuclear War
if %opt%==Chess goto Chess
if %opt%==Tic-Tac-Toe goto TicTacToe
if %opt%==Snake goto Snake
if %opt%==Global Thermonuclear War goto Global Thermonuclear War

:n 
echo Thats too bad! Maybe we should play some other day!
pause
exit

:chess

:tictactoe
echo Are you sure?
echo y/n
set response=
if %response%==y goto tictactoe1
if %response%==n goto tictactoe2

:tictactoe1
echo Go Back?
echo y/n
set feedback=
if %feedback%==y goto greeting
if %feedback%==n goto tictactoe2

:tictactoe2
echo testing
goto tictactoe2
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Notepad or Notepad++.

Comment: Notepad and Notepad++ are both text editors, and you can't program them. If you're not clear what language you're using, you shouldn't be trying to write code in it.

Comment: Edited tags, I hope I got it right.

Comment: basic troubleshooting: run it with `echo on` and start it from an open `cmd`window, not per Doubleclick. Then you will clearly see what happens. (I need a macro for this sentece...)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will be sure to try it but, @hyde what do you mean by edited tags

Comment: None of the troubleshooting worked, I think it might have something to do with the syntax

Comment: @Grey__X Under your question text, currently `batch-file` and `cmd`, those are your question's tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're trying to do:

```
@echo off
title Shall We Play a Game?
color 0b

set /a "tries=3"
set "password=Joshua"
:top
echo  %tries% Tries Remaining
set /p "pass=Password: "
if "%pass%"=="%password%" (
goto correct
)
set /a "tries=%tries% -1"
if %tries%==0 (
goto penalty
)
cls
goto top
:penalty
echo CONNECTION TERMINATED
pause
exit
:correct
goto greeting

:greeting
echo Shall we play a game?
echo y/n
set /p "input="
if "%input%"=="y" goto y
if "%input%"=="n" goto n

:y
echo How about
echo Chess
echo Tic-Tac-Toe
echo Snake
echo Global Thermonuclear War
set /P "opt="
if "%opt%"=="Chess" goto Chess
if "%opt%"=="Tic-Tac-Toe" goto TicTacToe
if "%opt%"=="Snake" goto Snake
if "%opt%"=="Global Thermonuclear War" goto GlobalThermonuclearWar

:n 
echo Thats too bad! Maybe we should play some other day!
pause
exit

:chess

:tictactoe
echo Are you sure?
echo y/n
set /p response=
if %response%==y goto tictactoe1
if %response%==n goto tictactoe2

:tictactoe1
echo Go Back?
echo y/n
set /p feedback=
if %feedback%==y goto greeting
if %feedback%==n goto tictactoe2

:tictactoe2
echo testing
goto tictactoe2
```

You forgot `/P` in a set a couple of times, this is used to get user input. In your `set /a tries=%tries -1` you also forgot to put a second `%` around tries, this should be `set /a tries=%tries% -1`. Furthermore, you should put `""` double quotes around your variables if you're comparing them, this prevents the script from braking if a variable doesn't exist or is empty. You also shouldn't have spaces in your labels, and you should put quotes around your set, like this: `set "variable=value"`, this prevents trailing spaces from getting in your variables

Comment: @Grey__X if my answer solved your problem, you should consider clicking the check to the left of it so people searching on google for the same problem can find it. See [this](//stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for why this is important.